# How to replace a method with an arbitrary function inside test function (not using patch.object)?

Tags: python, python-unittest, python-mock

My attempt was to mock the database operation inside a function with a predefined value.

I patched my mongo collection instance's `find` method and set a list of dictionary as a demo return value (`find` return more or less in similar data structure). But the problem is, `find` returns something that has a `count()` method, which takes no argument, while, The return value I set (a `list`) also has a `count()` method, but it takes a parameter and it's purpose is also different as well.

So, my target was to change the `count()`'s behavior so that it returns the `len` of the list I have hard coded. (the `len` of the return value of the `find` method)

Below is the code:

In some_module.py,

```
def somefunc():
    items = mongo_collection.find({"some_field": True}).batch_size(50)

    if items.count() > 0:
        counter += 1
```

In test_some_module.py,

```
@patch.object(some_module, 'mongo_collection')
def test_some_func(patched_collection):
    patched_collection.find.return_value.batch_size.return_value = \
                                              [{'id': 1}, {'id': 2}]
    patched_collection.find.return_value.batch_size.return_value.count = ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you want to test.

If for some reason you want have list-like "response" and it should act as response (i.e., have `count` method), you should create such object and set it as return value.

Now you setting `[{'id': 1}, {'id': 2}]`. As soon as you return this list via `mongo_collection.find().batch_size()`, result is actually a list, not mock. So, no further stuff like `.count = ...` available.

So, there's ways to go with:

1. Test response body and your count in different tests, patching connector differently
2. Create better response mock, i.e.

   ```
   class Response(list):
       def count(self):
           return len(self)
   ...
   patched_collection.find.return_value.batch_size.return_value = Response([{'id': 1}, {'id': 2}])
   ```
3. Create response mock as instance on response from your mock library

Comment: the function is a demo function as the original function contains complex business logic. I only included the part which creates problem for me. Anyway, got the idea. Thank you very much.